# I am trying to use EXCEL Trim function on a range of cells but it doesn't seem to work, instead it throws an error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Error Image]

I am trying to use the EXCEL Trim function on a range of cells but it doesn't seem to work, instead, it throws an error "#VALUE!". I am just beginning to learn Excel and was going through this W3Schools Learning Module on Excel, there under the TRIM Function they were able to use the function on a range of cells I am unable to do. Can someone help me out, please? I am using Office 2019

Comment: @Mike, please provide sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format

Answer (score 1):

On an array an array formula has to be used. Do the followings:

- Type the formula in a cell press ENTER
- Select an identical range to the source range with the formula in the top left cell.
- Click the formula bar and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

or

- Select an identical sized range on the sheet, click on formula bar and type the formula.
- Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 0):

Other Best way it to use power query where you can apply column transform over multiple column in same time . Power query is strong feature of excel that allow you to apply multiple step together with nested feature

```
    Source = YourTable,
    TrimmedColumn = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"ColumnName", Text.Trim, type text}})
in
    TrimmedColumn
```